# Unable to query projects using Tuleap REST API

Tags: rest, api, alm, tuleap

I am using Tuleap API to query projects using the below API

```
https://alm.test.com/api/projects?query={"shortname":"myproject"}
```

When I call this API, Its not returning results for the project "myproject" rather its returning all projects in Tuleap.

I used the same REST API on [Tuleap API Explorer](https://tuleap.net/api/explorer/#!/projects/retrieve) it works.

Am I missing something ?

[image]

Comment: Could you add which version of tuleap you are using and the status of the project (private, public, etc) you are looking for

Comment: The Tuleap Version is (8.13.99.10) got to know that the option to query using shortname is not available

Comment: Hi Manuel, I am looking to query artifacts for a given date and has the status "Backlog", could you help with this query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627204/unable-to-query-projects-using-tuleap-rest-api-to-get-artifacts-details