# Unable to query projects using Tuleap REST API - To Get Artifacts details

Tags: rest, api, alm, tuleap

I am using Tuleap (8.13.99.10) API to query artifacts.

Could you provide details how to query for based on date and status.

Where can I find (field_id,field_shortname) for date and status.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to query first the structure of the tracker with `GET /trackers/{id}`. In the response payload you will have all the details about the field names and ids

Comment: Yes found the details in GET /trackers/{id} , Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a more detailed doc I can use to explore the api apart form the official site http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.io/

Comment: As of today the only docs available are the API explorer and the official documentation. But if you find something that should be in the doc, let us know (or better propose a PR)

Comment: It would be good if there were some more examples on how to use the API.